# What applets are loaded in the gnome-panel?

Tags: gnome, gnome-panel, gsettings

**How can I list which applets are loaded on my gnome-panel?**

What gnome-panel do I have? I use the Ubuntu “gnome-panel” package and I’m not entirely sure what that means (version 3.4.1; `ldd` shows it depends on gtk3).

So far I’ve found that `gconf-editor` shows me some entries under `/apps/panel3-applets` E.g. `object_0_3`. It seems that those have something to do with the applets running and their configuration, but a) I have only five entries there (not enough) and b) they don’t reveal which files/packages those entries originate from.

With `gsettings list-recursively` I found an interesting entry:

```
org.gnome.gnome-panel.layout object-id-list ['menu-bar', 'clock', 'notification-area', 'user-menu', 'object-0-0', 'object-0-1', 'object-0-2', 'object-0-3', 'object-0-4', 'object-0-5']
```

It lists the objects I found in `gconf-editor` and some more. But here I don’t even see configuration entries or anything better.

From an applet I added myself I can say that the applet-chooser seems to be based on files found in `/usr/share/gnome-panel/4.0/applets/`, which contain a line telling the shared library to load by the panel (I guess). – **But after adding, where does the `gnome-panel` store which applets to load the next time??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is stored in

  $HOME/.config/dconf/user

You can see the settings with

  dconf dump /

or

  dconf-editor

Note: I figured this out by running

  find $HOME -mmin '-20' -exec ls -ld {} \; > /tmp/before

before and after adding an applet and diffing the results